# Flutter/Dart - type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a drop down list inside an alert dialog widget. The menu items need to be pulled from firebase. So far, I have created my alert dialog, looped through my firebase data and created a list from the results. The issue I am facing comes when I try to use my list as the "items" for my dropdown, when I run my code I get the following error:

```
type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'
```

Here is my code:

```
class ViewSingleCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imgUrl;
  final String message;

  ViewSingleCard({this.imgUrl, this.message});

  @override
  _ViewSingleCardState createState() => _ViewSingleCardState(imgUrl, message);
}

class _ViewSingleCardState extends State<ViewSingleCard> {
  String imgUrl;
  String message;

  _ViewSingleCardState(this.imgUrl, this.message);

  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = index;
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        title: Text('Viewer'),
        actions: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    createAlertDiaglog(context);
                  })
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Image(
                          image: FirebaseImage(imgUrl,
                              maxSizeBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024))),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(message),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(  
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                        if (i == currentPage)
                          SlideDots(true)
                        else
                          SlideDots(false)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }

  createAlertDiaglog(BuildContext context) {
    String selectedOccasion;
    List<DropdownMenuItem> occasions = [];
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Add to collection"),
            content: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: getCollectionInfo(context),
                // ignore: missing_return
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                    const Text("Loading.....");
                  else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                      DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                      occasions.add(
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(
                            snap.id,
                          ),
                          value: "${snap.id}",
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // ignore: missing_return
                      DropdownButton<String>(
                        items: occasions,
                        hint: Text("Style"),
                        value: selectedOccasion,
                        onChanged: (String Value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedOccasion = Value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          );
        });
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getCollectionInfo(BuildContext context) async* {
    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('collections')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('occasions')
        .snapshots();
  }
}
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: I supposed your DropdownButton needs to be DropdownMenuItem instead of string, since you putting occasions into your items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the fix, add the `<String>` there:

```
                      occasions.add(
                        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          child: Text(
```

and also fix the type of the list (thanks to @nvoigt's answer)

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> occasions = [];
```

Your `DropDownButton` is given the `<String>` type, so it's expecting the same thing from its items.

Whenever you get this exception, just swap the locations of the two types and think of an assignment. This means you are trying to do this kind of assignment

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> a;
List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>> b;
a = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem> occasions = [];
```

is a `List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>`, but you want a `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>`, so you need to make it one:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> occasions = [];
```

That said: you have an analyzer. Do *not* ignore it's warnings. You have ignored warnings that are correct, where you have made a mistake. Do not do this. Do not *ignore* your mistakes, *fix* them.